# Given n, how many strings of length n with only an alphabet of {1,2,3} can you make

Tags: string, math, recurrence

...such that nowhere in the string would there be a substring of length 3 where all 3 numbers exist?

In other words, how many strings exist such that none of the following: "123", "132", "213", "231", "312", or "321" are substrings?

I stumbled across a problem like this and am trying to figure out the recurrence, but my recurrence is incorrect (I compared it in code to a brute force program).

My recurrence at the moment is :

```
f(n) = 3f(n - 1) - 6f(n - 3)
```

We know that we have all the possible strings given by f(n) = 3f(n - 1)
we also know that there are 6 ways we don't want to consider:

```
123 concatenated with all the ways to make f(n-3)
132 concatenated with all the ways to make f(n-3)
213 concatenated with all the ways to make f(n-3)
231 concatenated with all the ways to make f(n-3)
312 concatenated with all the ways to make f(n-3)
321 concatenated with all the ways to make f(n-3)
```

Is there some insight I'm missing here? It makes sense in my head, but it's not correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a general equation or algorithm rather than any actual programming problem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you can turn this into a programming problem by changing the sample to `int f(int n) { if (n==3) return 27-6; else return 3*f(n-1) - 6*f(n-3); }` and adding a `C` tag. I think this is a valid programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

Easy explainable approach:
Let's

`F(n) = P(n, 2) + P(n, 1)`

where P(n, 2) is number of strings, ending with **two different digits** (like xxx13),
and  P(n, 1) is number of strings, ending with **two equal digits** (like xxx22).

Then

```
P(n, 2) = P(n - 1, 2) + 2 * P(n-1, 1)  
//we can add only a to the end of xxxab, and both b and c to xxxaa

P(n, 1) = P(n - 1, 2) + P(n - 1, 1)   
//we can add only b to xxxab, and only a to xxxaa
//note it is equal to F(n-1)

F(n) = 2 * P(n - 1, 2) + 3 * P(n - 1, 1) = 
       2 * (P(n - 1, 2) + P(n - 1, 1)) + P(n - 1, 1) =
       2 * F(n - 1) + P(n - 1, 1) =
       2 * F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)
```

with initial values

```
F(1) = 3
P(2, 2) = 6
P(2, 1) = 3
F(2) = 9
```

For example:

```
F(3) = 21 (9 * 2 + 3) (quick check: 3^3 - 3! = 27 - 6 = 21)
F(4) = 51
F(5) = 123
F(6) = 297
F(7) = 717
```

So:

```
 F(n) = 2 * F(n - 1)  +  F(n - 2)
```